# MYSQL: What is wrong with my basic query?

Tags: mysql

We are practicing the IN clause. I have a customer table with the columns: customerID, fname, lnanme, city, state

My objective is to Select the first name, city, and state from the customers table for all of the rows where the state value is either: Arizona, Washington, Oklahoma, Colorado, or Hawaii.

My query is

```
select fname, city, state 
from customer
where state IN (Arizona, Washington, Oklahoma, Colorado, Hawaii);
```

I'm getting the error: Unknown Column 'Arizona' in 'where clause'

Comment: `IN ('Arizona', 'Washington', 'Oklahoma', 'Colorado', 'Hawaii')`

Comment: You need single quotes around constants.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arizona, etc., are text values, so should be surrounded with 'apostrophes', otherwise it considers that they are field names.

Comment: Oh thank you. The example we were given was with numeric values so it didn't occur to me

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `'` before and after the strings

```
select fname, city, state 
from customer
where state IN ('Arizona', 'Washington', 'Oklahoma', 'Colorado', 'Hawaii');
```

Hope this helps